# Getting Braintree payments to work with One Step Checkout by iDev

Tags: magento-1.9, onestepcheckout

We are trying to integrate Braintree payments with our one step checkout within in Magento 1.9.1.

Has anybody been able to get braintree working with a multistore magento?

When we turn off One Step Checkout we can connect to the braintree sandbox fine and perform test transactions. Each time we enable it we get the following error:

```
The requested Payment Method is not available.

XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Info.php(82): Mage::throwException('The requested P...')
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Payment.php(218): Mage_Payment_Model_Info->getMethodInstance()
XXX\app\code\local\Braintree\Payments\Block\Form.php(34): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment->getMethodInstance()
[internal function]: Braintree_Payments_Block_Form->setMethodInfo()
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
XXX\app\code\local\Idev\OneStepCheckout\controllers\IndexController.php(49): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Idev_OneStepCheckout_IndexController->indexAction()
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
XXX\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
XXX\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
XXX\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
{main}
```

Comment: this is caused by faults in braintree method where it can't actually initiate itself where payment object is not jet set in quote

Comment: @Gavin which OneStepCheckout module are you using?  We are thinking of going with Braintree and they advised we use [this module](http://www.onestepcheckout.com/) as it was the only one they could guarantee would work.

Answer (score 1):

change the Braintree_Payments_Block_Form and add one method and change one mehtod

```
public function getMethod()
{
    //again when the block does not have a method set it will fail miserably so make sure that we init this when block is requested it will not initiate itself 
    $method = $this->getData('method');

    if (!($method instanceof Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract)) {
       $this->setMethod(Mage::helper('payment')->getMethodInstance('braintree'));
    }
    return parent::getMethod();
}

/**
 * Set quote and payment
 *
 * @return Braintree_Payments_Block_Form
 */
public function setMethodInfo()
{
    //this caused a issue when this block tried to set a nonexisting method to itself, let's limit this to braintree only 
    $this->setMethod('braintree');
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Braintree Payments have gone leaps and bounds in the last few months, both commercially and technologically. They now offer two solutions that feature out-of-the-box PCI compliance (using invisible iframes). "v.zero **drop-in**" looks very slick and has great UX, but is less customisable. The second one, "**Hosted Fields**" is also very smart and allows more control in terms of CSS styling and layout.

Luckily, for seamless integration into Magento *without you having to do* *any* *coding*, there are already extensions on Magento Connect to make implementation of either of the above effortless, see for instance http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer/f+r+i+s

Here's a comparison to help you choose the best one for your store: https://fris.technology/blog/braintree-drop-in-or-hosted-fields

These extensions work in Mage core's multi-step checkout as as well as in combination with almost any one-page/one-step checkout extension on the Magento Marketplace, including Idev/OneStepCheckout.com